# Python3: unit measures associated to variables

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, annotations, comments

As a decades-old-programmer, I learned the hard way, that it makes sense for phyisical values to put a tag to a variable. In C or C++, I do it with in-line remarks:

**Code in C**

```
double /*MOhm*/ resistance(double R1 /*MOhm*/, double R2 /*MOhm*/){
    return R1+R2;
}
```

comment purpose: *inputs are MOhm's and output is MOhm too.*

Is there a elegant Pythonian way to do the same? As there are no inline remarks, how can one do it? It is very important for me to have a readable code, which is easily understood by another person.

Comment: I do block comments, describing all variables units (and purposes and restrictions) at once. Seems to fit in "naturally", especially if you put it right after the string describing the function/method.

Comment: I would rather use names `R1_MOhm` or similar. These comments are ugly if you ask me.

Comment: @NominalAnimal: Do you mean something like """R1  MOhm, R2 MOhm """ ?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I do that too, that works fine. But: What about the return value?

Comment: `resistance_MOhm`?

Comment: @EugeneSh., does this mean that you call the function:  **double resistance_MOhm (....)** ?

Comment: Depending on the naming style you choose. But it's only a personal opinion.

Comment: I use more like """This function does FOO. (empty line) R1 is the resistance of BAR in megaohms, R2 the resistance of BAZ in megaohms. (empty line) The return value is the resulting resistance in megaohms. (empty line) The function will raise Frob exception if the input parameters do not make sense.""" where the intent of the block comment is to 1) describe the purpose/intent of the function, 2) describe the variables and their limitations, 3) describe the return value, and 4) any exceptions the function might raise.  This seems to work: I can maintain my old code.  Pretty? I dunno. Verbose.

Comment: I haven't done C in a very long time, but is there an argument against simply defining a new type for this? `typedef MOhm = double; MOhm resistance(MOhm R1, MOhm R2) { return R1 + R2; }`

Comment: @NominalAnimal: that's exellent, I will include also your point of exception into my programming style.

Comment: @chepner: great idea, this avoids many software bugs in C++ and C, as one cannot compile if it is the wrong unit. But how shall we do that in Python?

Comment: @MarcelSonderegger See my answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be specific: define a type (type alias, actually) that describes exactly what you expect.

```
MOhm = float

def resistance(r1: MOhm, r2: MOhm) -> MOhm:
    return r1 + r2
```

(Python 3 does allow Unicode identifiers, so you could get fancy and write

```
# That's M\u2126, M + OHM SIGN
MΩ = float

def resistance(r1: MΩ, r2: MΩ) -> MΩ:
    return r1 + r2
```

However, `U+03a9` (Ω, GREEK CAPITAL LETTER OMEGA) and `U+2126` (Ω, OHM SIGN) are at best difficult to tell apart, so I would avoid this kind of identifier in real code.)

---

You can go a step further and define a *real* new type that tools like `mypy` will enforce. There is a small run-time cost to doing so, however.

```
from typing import NewType

Ohm = NewType("Ohm", float)
MOhm = NewType("MOhm", float)

def resistance(r1: MOhm, r2: MOhm) -> MOhm:
    return MOhm(r1 + r2)

x: Ohm = Ohm(3.0)
y: MOhm = MOhm(4.0)

# mypy error, resistance expects its first argument to have type MOHm, not OHm
print(resistance(x, y))
```

`NewType` is a helper function for defining classes like

```
class Ohm(float):
    pass

class MOhm(float):
    pass
```

At runtime, all three classes behave the same. Tools like `mypy`, however, will treat them as distinct classes, making you work harder to ensure
your code typechecks. It's harder to accidentally make unit errors when you
have to be specific about the values you pass.

Comment: Wow, that simple: great. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Python you should use a function [docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring) describing the parameters and return values. For example, using [sphinx](https://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/sphinx.html) syntax:

```
def resistance(r1: float, r2: float) -> float:
    """
    Calculate resistance.

    :param r1: resistance in MOhm
    :param r2: resistance in MOhm
    :returns: total resistance in MOhm
    """
    return r1 + r2
```

Docstrings in standard formats can be parsed by IDEs to provide you useful auto-completion, etc.